# status code showing 200 but file not uploaded

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to upload image/audio/video from gallery from my android app to php server, when uploading the server is giving response `200`, but when i see my server folder, its empty. Kindly check my code for any error. In the manifest I gave the required permissions also, I am doing it using Android Studio

`VideoActivity.java`

```
//android upload file to server
    public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){

        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";


        int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; //Max File Size
        File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


        String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

        if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
            dialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
                }
            });
            return 0;
        }else{
            try{
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
                connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
                connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

                //creating new dataoutputstream
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                //writing bytes to data outputstream
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

                //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                while (bytesRead > 0){
                    //write the bytes read from inputstream
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                }

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textViewResponse.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n");
                        }
                    });
                }

                //closing the input and output streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();



            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;
        }

    }
```

`FilePath.java`

```
public class FilePath {
    /**
     * Method for return file path of Gallery image/ Document / Video / Audio
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @return path of the selected image file from gallery
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                            + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                        Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context
     *            The context.
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to query.
     * @param selection
     *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs
     *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                       String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = { column };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }
}
```

PHP code

```
<?php
    $file_path = "VideoUploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `success` or `fail` what are you getting? Make sure you have write permission on server. And uploaded file size is less than server file size limit (if any). And make sure the file extension of the file you are uploading is permitted on server

Comment: hi, whoever is giving downvote, pls mention why giving the same, so that i know my fault, thnx

Comment: Status code 200 means the site was loaded successfully, it says **nothing** about whether or not the video or image is uploaded

Comment: @AswinPAshok.........i m getting Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode); --> output as "OK" and "200"

Answer (score 1):

You're basing your check on the wrong factor. The server gives you a [200](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) status code because the site itself is fine, it loads, file is found, no redirects, no 404, no errors. The **loading** went fine.

The status code says **nothing what so ever** as to whether or not the video or image was uploaded successfully.

Instead of checking for the status code that will return 200 assuming the site is fine, and the URL is loaded, check what the site says after it finishes.

```
if(serverResponseMessage.equals("success")){
     //Success! Do whatever
} else {
     //In your script, it fails if it goes here
}
```

Whether or not you get a 200 status code has nothing to do with whether or not the upload succeeds

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved. The problem was in php.ini file, max file upload size was 2MB, i increased it and everything is working perfectly. thanks